# Escape ;(semicolon) in odbc connection string in app.config file

Tags: c#, string

I have created a windows form with certain fields. I am trying to interact with oracle database through ODBC DSN connections.

I have an issue in the below connection string in app.config .

In the connection string password contains semicolon(here abc;45). I am getting an error:

`"Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 35"`

while i am trying to access this connection string using

`OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connection_string);`

in C# code.

Below is my connection string.

```
<add name="ConnectionString_T1" connectionString="DSN=CLA_T5;Uid=abc;Pwd=abc;45" providerName="System.Data.Odbc" />

 OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connection_string);
```

PS: I tried putting this password in double quotes/single quote/" . But no use. Still facing this error. I have tried putting all the escape sequences like ",double quote, single quote,/" etc..

Comment: Forgot ot metion connection string. Here it is <add name="ConnectionString_T1" connectionString="DSN=CLA_T5;Uid=abc;Pwd=abc;45" providerName="System.Data.Odbc" />

Comment: Can you tell us how you were able to assign the connection string to the `connection_string` variable?

Comment: string connection_string = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CLAConnectionString_T1"].ConnectionString;

Comment: Looking at what you've posted, shouldn't it be `string connection_string = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString_T1"].ConnectionStrin‌​g;` ? Or was this deliberate?

Comment: i didn't get you @rikitikitik

Comment: The connection string name in your App.config is different from the name you're using in that last code you posted. "CLAConnectionString_T1" versus "ConnectionString_T1". Ultimately, it doesn't matter, though :)

Comment: Sorry, actually it was a typo here..i am using the correct connection string name as in app.config file

Answer (score 25):

Rikitikitik is partly correct about escaping `[]{(),;?*=!@` characters in an ODBC Connection String by surrounding the value with `{}` , but misses a subtle but extremely important ODBC Connection String escape rule that is NOT documented by Microsoft about escaping `}`.

`PASS CASE: connectionString="DSN=CLA_T5;Uid=abc;Pwd={abc;45}"`

Works correctly to escape the `;`, but will fail when the password is

`FAIL CASE: connectionString="DSN=CLA_T5;Uid=abc;Pwd={abc;}45}"`

Because the first `}` character is interpreted as the closing brace of the escape pair, rather than the second (correct) `}`.

To correct for this, you have to manually escape the `}` with a second `}`

`PASS CASE: connectionString="DSN=CLA_T5;Uid=abc;Pwd={abc;}}45}"`, which will be read as `abc;}45}` by the ODBC engine.

This appears to be a totally undocumented, despite several MSDN sources outlining the enclosing `{}` escaping Rikitikitik mentions.

Documentation failing to mention the interior `}` escape method:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbcconnection.connectionstring(v=vs.110).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130822.aspx

However, the interior `}` escape method is clearly observable with a quick .net test harness:

```
OdbcConnectionStringBuilder builder = new OdbcConnectionStringBuilder
builder.Driver = "{SomeDriver}"
builder.Add("UID", "user");
builder.Add("PWD", "abc;}45"); 

MessageBox.Show(builder.ConnectionString) // observe PWD's escaped value of "{abc;}}45}"

try
{
    using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
    {
        //           
        MessageBox.Show("SUCCEEDED");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"{ResourceManager.GetString("FAILED: ")} {ex.Message}");
}
```

where `SomeDriver` has a user `user` with password `abc;}45`

Answer (score 9):

I ran into a similar problem with an entity framework connection string.  While I was not using an `OdbcConnection` I thought I would add what worked for me to help anyone with my issue that was similar.
We had a password created with a semicolon in it.  And it broke our entity framework connection string.  The error was:

> 'Keyword not supported: '[rest of password after semicolon];multipleactiveresultsets'.'

I resolved the issue by placing single quotes (') around the username and password fields.
The result was a connection string that contained the following:

```
initial catalog=myDB;User     
Id='MyUser';Password='abc;123';multipleactiveresultsets=True;
```

Comment: This answer worked for me when none of the others did.

Comment: Just like Pete, curly braces didn't work for me in .NET cals to SQL server, but this did. I also had an apostrophe inside the password; I tried escaping it with two apostrophes (eg: Password='abc''123', for the password abc'123) and that worked.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, ODBC is special when it comes to escaping connection string values with semicolons, equal signs, etc. According to [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21649868), you should enclose values with special characters in curly braces {}

```
connectionString="DSN=CLA_T5;Uid=abc;Pwd={abc;45}"
```

Comment: @Punith Check out my edit. ODBC does things a bit differently when escaping connection strings.

Comment: When i put my password in curly braces, it is throwing as invalid username/password error..

Answer (score 1):

Try this connection string...

```
<add name="ConnectionString_T1" connectionString="DSN=CLA_T5;Uid='abc';Pwd='abc;45';" providerName="System.Data.Odbc" />
```

I am using same type of tricky password and solve this issue in this way....

Comment: I tried your way..but no luck..now my connection string looks like this DSN=CLA_T5;Uid=CLA_T5;Pwd='abc;45'

Comment: Sagar, It didn't work..but i tried changing the position of the DSN,Uid,Pwd as "Uid='CLA_T5';Pwd='abc;45';DSN=CLA_T5"..it passed the earlier exception..but exception has been thrown while opening the connection connection.Open();..exception was  "Data source name not found and no default driver specified
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection."..I checked DSN was present in the ODBC administartor in the SystemDsn section

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and based on Microsoft document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlConnection_ConnectionString
I used double quotes (which didn't work) and then single quotes around the password worked. Something like:

```
var connectionString = "Data Source={datasource};Initial Catalog={InitialCatalog};User Id={LocalUserId};Password='{LocalPassword}';
```

Where LocalPassword and LocalUserId are just class members.

Answer (score -1):

Try one of these:

```
<add name="ConnectionString_T1" connectionString="DSN=CLA_T5;Uid=abc;Pwd='abc;45'" providerName="System.Data.Odbc" />

<add name="ConnectionString_T1" connectionString="DSN=CLA_T5;Uid=abc;Pwd=&quot;abc;45&quot;" providerName="System.Data.Odbc" />
```

> Please take this as a starting point and not as a copy-paste solution

Comment: Hi, I have tried all the possible ways of escaping this semi colan like 1.&quot;abc;45&quot; 2.'abc;45' 3. \"abc;45\" 4.abc&quot;;45..in the app.config file..but while i read this connection string and pass it to the class like OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connection_string);..it thows Format error..

Comment: How about using the SQL Connection String builder? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx

Comment: I am getting error "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index"..however, i am using Oracle client 10g

Comment: Can you try using the SQL Connection String builder...you may build the connection string using some other temporary project...just pass the required parameter and then and then output it as string to paste it in the config file. Thoughts!