# SQL Server 2008 password ending in a semicolon

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Let's say I have a password that looks like this:  password;

How can I get it to work with a semicolon as the last character.  The password works in SSMS and ODBC, but not with the connection string.  I've tried `&quot;` around it but that does not seem to work.

```
<add name="DbConn" connectionString="Data Source=LOCALHOST;Database=MYDB;Trusted_Connection=no;User Id=myuser;Password=password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This is for an ASP.NET web application.  As far as I can tell, it is impossible.  UPDATE:  It IS possible!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Encapsulate your password in single quotes.  e.g. given the password `iloveachallenge;` your connection string should contain `Password='iloveachallenge;';`.

I am using the following code to connect to SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
  var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection()
            {
                ConnectionString = "Server=DT2719MOD;Database=abs2;User Id=TestUserLogon;Password='iloveachallenge;';"

            };
        sqlConnection.Open();
        Console.WriteLine(sqlConnection.State);
        sqlConnection.Close();
```

Edit:
Also tried to use the connection string that you have and it works on my machine.

```
ConnectionString="Data Source=DT2719MOD;Database=abs2;Trusted_Connection=no;User Id=TestUserLogon;Password='iloveachallenge;';"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I created a new web app and tried your solution and it worked.  Same user/pw in my main app did not work, so now I need to figure out what is going on there.  But now I know it is possible.

Comment: If you have a `stringconnection` with `<parameters>` elements instead of attributes, this method works. 

`<connectionString name="MyConnectionString">
          <parameters>
            <parameter name="Data Source" value="1.2.3.4" isSensitive="false" />
            <parameter name="Initial Catalog" value="MyCATALOG" isSensitive="false" />
            <parameter name="Password" value="'.MyP4$$W0rD;'" isSensitive="true" />
            <parameter name="User ID" value="myUserName" isSensitive="false" />
          </parameters>
        </connectionString>`

Answer (score 5):

To include values that contain a semicolon, single-quote character, or double-quote character, the value must be enclosed in double quotes.

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms722656(v=vs.85).aspx

Basically you have there all the escaping procedures of a connection string.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. The answer is given in Pete's answer in this thread: [Escape ;(semicolon) in odbc connection string in app.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398212/escape-semicolon-in-odbc-connection-string-in-app-config-file)

Basically, you need to put single quotes around the Username/Password **fields**, not the characters you want to escape, which is where I was going wrong.

To steal Pete's example:

```
initial catalog=myDB;UserId=MyUser;Password=abc;123;multipleactiveresultsets=True;
```

needs to become:

```
initial catalog=myDB;UserId='MyUser';Password='abc;123';multipleactiveresultsets=True;
```