# (Maybe) Illegal character in ODBC SQL Server Connection String PWD=

Tags: odbc, connection-string, sql-server-express

According to what I have researched there are no illegal characters in the PWD= field of a SQL Server Connection String.

However, using SQL Server Express 2008 I changed the SA password to a GUID, specifically:

> {85C86BD7-B15F-4C51-ADDA-3B6A50D89386}

So when connecting via ODBC I use this connection string:

```
"Driver={SQL Server};Server=.\\MyInstance;Database=Master;UID=SA;PWD={85C86BD7-B15F-4C51-ADDA-3B6A50D89386};"
```

But it comes back as Login failed for SA.

However, if I change the SA password to something just as long but without **{}-** it succeeds! Are there certain characters in PWD= that need to be escaped?  I tried all different combinations with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-2017) states (emphasis added) --

> Connection strings used by ODBC have the following syntax:
>
> ```
> connection-string ::= empty-string[;] | attribute[;] | attribute; connection-string
>
> empty-string ::=
>
> attribute ::= attribute-keyword=[{]attribute-value[}]
>
> attribute-value ::= character-string
>
> attribute-keyword ::= identifier
> ```
>
> Attribute values can optionally be enclosed in braces, and it is good practice to do so. This avoids problems when attribute values contain non-alphanumeric characters. **The first closing brace in the value is assumed to terminate the value, so values cannot contain closing brace characters.**

I would suggest you simply remove the braces when you set the password, and then the connect string you provided above should work fine.

### ADDITION

I dug a bit further on Microsoft's site, and found some [ABNF rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/sql_server_protocols/ms-odbcstr/f2c5a055-557c-47d9-ab06-1d7b985b6769) which may be relevant --

> ```
>  SC           = %x3B         ; Semicolon 
>  LCB          = %x7B         ; Left curly brackets 
>  RCB          = %x7D         ; Right curly brackets  
>  EQ           = %x3D         ; Equal sign 
>  ESCAPEDRCB   = 2RCB         ; Double right curly brackets 
>  SpaceStr     = *(SP)        ; Any number (including 0) spaces
>  ODBCConnectionString =  *(KeyValuePair SC) KeyValuePair [SC]
>  KeyValuePair = (Key EQ Value / SpaceStr)
>  Key = SpaceStr KeyName
>  KeyName = (nonSP-SC-EQ *nonEQ)
>  Value = (SpaceStr ValueFormat1 SpaceStr) / (ValueContent2)
>  ValueFormat1 = LCB ValueContent1 RCB
>  ValueContent1 = *(nonRCB / ESCAPEDRCB)
>  ValueContent2 = SpaceStr / SpaceStr (nonSP-LCB-SC) *nonSC
>  nonRCB = %x01-7C / %x7E- FFFF                                 ; not "}"
>  nonSP-LCB-SC = %x01-1F / %x21-3A / %x3C-7A / %x7C- FFFF       ; not space, "{" or ";"
>  nonSP-SC-EQ = %x01-1F / %x21-3A / %x3C / %x3E- FFFF           ; not space, ";" or "="
>  nonEQ = %x01-3C / %x3E- FFFF                                  ; not "="
>  nonSC = %x01-003A / %x3C- FFFF                                ; not ";"
> ```

...

> `ValueFormat1` is recommended to use when there is a need for `Value` to contain `LCB`, `RCB`, or `EQ`. `ValueFormat1` MUST be used when the `Value` contains `SC` or starts with `LCB`.
>
> `ValueContent1` MUST be enclosed by `LCB` and `RCB`. Spaces before the enclosing `LCB` and after the enclosing `RCB` MUST be ignored.
>
> `ValueContent1` MUST be contained in `ValueFormat1`. If there is an `RCB` in the `ValueContent1`, it MUST use the two-character sequence `ESCAPEDRCB` to represent the one-character value `RCB`.

All of which comes down to...  I believe the following connect string *should* work for you (note that there are 2 left/open braces and 3 right/close braces on the PWD value) --

```
"Driver={SQL Server};Server=.\\MyInstance;Database=Master;UID=SA;PWD={{85C86BD7-B15F-4C51-ADDA-3B6A50D89386}}};"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately the choice of SA password is not mine. So you are saying that in a connection string the PWD= cannot contain {brackets}? Because it is perfectly legal when setting the SA password in Management Studio.

Comment: I should have named this topic _"How to escape left brace in an ODBC connection string"_. After more testing and research it turns out that that right brace is no problem. However I have not found a way to escape the left brace. Possibly there isn't one.

Comment: I've edited my answer. SQL Server password `{123}` *should* be passable in the ODBC connect string as `PWD={{123}}}`. (Imbalanced braces are intentional.)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/some-odbc-applications-may-not-be-able-handle-special-characters-tablecolumn-names), the only legal "special character" in a name (I think they're talking about the DSN) is the UNDERSCORE:

> The ODBC specification (and the SQL specification) states that names
> must be in the format of " letter[digit | letter | _]...". The only
> special character allowed is an underscore.

There was no reference to "the ODBC Specification".  [This page](https://github.com/microsoft/ODBC-Specification/blob/master/ODBC%204.0.md) says it's the the ODBC 4.0 Spec.