# SQL password starting with =

Tags: sql, entity-framework, azure

I have webapp deployed in Azure.  I am continuously getting error, below.  I checked my SQL connection string it is valid. I am using EF core and SQL Azure database.

> System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not
>   conform to specification starting at index 157. at
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String
>   connectionString

My password in connection string was starting with "=". I changed that with a new password and it started working. eg : Password "==3-@5KvZ^WX@hMST"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23014180/sql-server-2008-password-ending-in-a-semicolon, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177861/escape-quote-in-web-config-connection-string,

Answer (score 0):

my password in connection string was starting with =. i changed that with new password and it started working.
eg :
Password==3-@5KvZ^WX@hMST