# How to have the semicolon character in a password for a SQL connection string?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

My connection string:

```
con = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=mainDB;User Id=sqluser;Password=Y;9r.5JQ6cwy@)V_");
```

That semicolon in the password causes an exception. How do I write this password into a connection string?

Comment: Why not just use a different character in your password? Change it to a carat or something. ^

Comment: Enclose the password value in quotes.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm not the database admin, I don't have permission.

Comment: @DanGuzman Double quotes work too, if that's not what you meant.

Comment: use `SqlConnectionStringBuilder`

Comment: @juharr, yes, either single or double quotes ought to work.

Comment: That password will now be in the known passwords lists of crackers - you'd probably best ask the database admin to change it ASAP unless you just made it up.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you considered using [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx)?

```
var sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
{
    DataSource = "localhost",
    InitialCatalog = "mainDB",
    Password = "Y;9r.5JQ6cwy@)V_",
    UserID = "sqluser"
};

con = new SqlConnection(sqlBuilder.ToString());
```

Comment: You beat me to it :) `sqlBuilder.ConnectionString` can be used instead of `sqlBuilder.ToString()`.

Comment: This one is the one that should be used. The password has a semi in it now, but later on it could have other characters that need escaping that are less straight forward, like single and double quotes. I put a single quote, a double quote and a semi in my password field just to test it out and the output was so ugly. Much easier just to use this one than to try to escape it yourself.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Or rather, it only answer the question is you really do supply the connection string from within C# code, rather than e.g. having to supply it in some config file.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper `Or rather, it only answer the question is you really do supply the connection string from within C# code, rather than e.g. having to supply it in some config file.` Given the question is tagged C#, it seems like a safe bet.

Comment: @DerrickMoeller: Wouldn't say so, that can just as well mean the config file needs to be read using C# code. Or the OP might even assume the format of the config file/connection string depends on C# (which it doesn't, I think; it probably depends only on the DB engine, but it's a reasonable assumption given that e.g. the exact capabilities of other structured text such as RegEx *does* depend on the runtime it is parsed by).

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I think you're stretching given the OP's original sample is using a `SqlConnection` object, but I suppose we'll just have to agree to disagree.

Answer (score 26):

Simply use like this.

```
con = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=mainDB;User Id=sqluser;Password='Y;9r.5JQ6cwy@)V_'");
```

Comment: For more info 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23014180/sql-server-2008-password-ending-in-a-semicolon

Comment: I believe this one is the clear answer, adding `'` as prefix and suffix.

Comment: what if passwrod contains all following chars  ; ' " {  }
Answer by Derrick Moeller is the correct one.

Answer (score 12):

Try using

```
Password='Y;9r.5JQ6cwy@)V_'
```

or

```
Password={Y;9r.5JQ6cwy@)V_}
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms722656(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: what if passwrod contains all following chars  ; ' " {  }
Answer by Derrick Moeller is the correct one.

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url?view=sql-server-ver15#escaping-values-in-the-connection-url) are the docs that state that braces are for escaping special characters in a jdbc connection string (url).

Answer (score 3):

Say your password is `ridi";'culous`. You can't just surround it with quotes, right?

The clever approach in [Derrick Moeller's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45742322/12534), using SqlConnectionStringBuilder, shows how to escape any character.

The answer is: `Password="ridi"";'culous"`

1. Surround the password with double quotes
2. Escape double quotes as `""`

In a JSON file, this of course must be escaped further, and now it's getting a bit hairy:

```json
"DefaultConnection": "Data Source=1.2.3.4;User Id=Me;Password=\"ridi\"\";'culous\"",
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps set SqlCredentials afterwards:

```
con = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost;Database=mainDB;User Id=sqluser;Password=dummy");
con.Credential = new SqlCredential("sqluser", "Y;9r.5JQ6cwy@)V_");
```