# System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 148

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to connect to my Azure SQL Database and am getting the following error below.  I have checked and the credentials are correct and allow me to connect to the database via SSMS. I have also tried logging the connection string and it shows correctly.

```
"ConnectionStrings:Database": "Server=tcp:myServerName.database.windows.net;Database=myDBName;User ID=MyUserID;Password=MyPassword"
```

````
 Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 148.
         at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)
         at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Dictionary`2 parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean firstKey)
         at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Dictionary`2 synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)
         at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String value)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String connectionString)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.<>c.<get_IsMultipleActiveResultSetsEnabled>b__7_0(String cs)
         at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func`2 valueFactory)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.get_IsMultipleActiveResultSetsEnabled()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Query.Internal.SqlServerCompiledQueryCacheKeyGenerator.GenerateCacheKey(Expression query, Boolean async)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.InternalDbSet`1.System.Collections.Generic.IAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Program.<>c.<<<Main>$>b__0_2>d.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Shayan\source\repos\CCHListenerApi\Program.cs:line 26
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.<ExecuteTaskOfT>g__ExecuteAwaited|112_0[T](Task`1 task, HttpContext httpContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)```
````

Comment: Does the password contain any characters that might mess things up? Like `;` or a quote character? If so see https://stackoverflow.com/q/45742155/73226