# Support Redshift DNS password SSIS Config File

Tags: ssis, config

The Amazon Redshift team generated a random password for us that includes a semicolon. When trying to use the password in an SSIS config file to configure the connection to Redshift, we get an error because SSIS thinks the semicolon is the end of string character. How can we include semicolons, and other special characters, in our connection strings?

Comment: How are you generating the passwords? This seems like an issue with your password generator, and not SSIS...

Comment: Thanks ! The password is at random generated by Redshift team and we cant control their functioning . I want to make some provision in ETL config file to read password if generated with semicolon.

Comment: So the Redshift team generated a password for you that contains a semicolon, and the semicolon is causing an error when you include it in your SSIS config file?

Comment: Yes Exactly! It gives connection error message as it treats Semicolon end of string .

Comment: Have you tried putting your password string in single quotes in the config file? Like: `PWD='pass;word'`

Comment: Take a look at this question and the currently highest voted answer. It has a lot of good, undocumented information about escaping special characters in connection strings. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398212/escape-semicolon-in-odbc-connection-string-in-app-config-file

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. i will try it out  and I did tried using '' so my config file has dynamic variable declared as Redshift Password=Password2. password 2 on runtime gets populated with random string generated by Redshift.I tried {} as well no luck.

Comment: Can you show exactly how you're building the connection string? Also, where is Password2 stored? Your variable, or connection string, probably needs an extra escape sequence.

Comment: What mechanism replaces the `RedshiftPassword2` text with the actual password from Redshift?

Comment: I have included config file in my ETL package configuration and named it to exact same name variable .

Comment: Where are you using the variable inside your SSIS package?

Comment: connection manager of redshift connection in my etl

Comment: how can I use semicolon in connection string ssis config file