# Connecting to Azure SQL database using DBI in R and ActiveDirectoryPassword authentication

Tags: r, azure, odbc, azure-sql-database, dbi

I want to connect to AzureSQL database using DBI in R. I want to manage this connection via AzureAD `ActiveDirectoryPassword` authentication. This requires me to state the AzureAD `UID` and `Password`.

I have verified that I can connect to this server using other authentication methods.

Running the code below results in an error :

```
DBI::dbConnect(
            odbc()
            , Driver = "SQL Server"
            , .connection_string = 
                    sprintf("server=%s;database=dbName;UID=%s;PWD=%s;Authentication=%s;"
                            , 'sqlservername.database.windows.net'
                            , 'justin@contoso.com'
                            , pwd # Let's just assume this is securely done for now
                            , 'ActiveDirectoryPassword'))
```

Expected result was to connect to the database

Actual result was the following:

```
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:950: HY000: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot open server "contoso.com" requested by the login.  The login failed.
```

I think the `@` in the username is not behaving in the way I initially expected that it might. How do I make this connection work? - I think I just need to find the correct format to express (escape?) the username.

Comment: I found something on escaping characters in ODBC : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398212/escape-semicolon-in-odbc-connection-string-in-app-config-file

Comment: Does your code work now?

Comment: No, I was able to eliminate the idea that the `@` needs escaping as a possible solution though

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
DBI::dbConnect(
            odbc()
            , Driver = "SQL Server"
            , .connection_string = 
                    sprintf("server=%s;database=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s;Authentication=%s;"
                            , 'sqlservername.database.windows.net'
                            , 'databasename'
                            , 'user@company.com'
                            , pwd # Let's just assume this is securely done for now
                            , 'ActiveDirectoryPassword'))
```