# Semicolon (;) in password causes 'invalid argument' when connecting

Tags: c#, .net, db2

I have been given a username and password to log onto a DB2 database.  I am using the IBM.Data.DB2 api.

The password I have been given has a semicolon in it: "pass;word".

Attempting to connect like this:

```
DB2ConnectionStringBuilder connStrBuilder = new DB2ConnectionStringBuilder();
connStrBuilder.Server = "10.10.10.55:50000";
connStrBuilder.Database = "databasename";
connStrBuilder.UserID = "username";
connStrBuilder.Password = "pass;word";
DB2Connection connection = new DB2Connection(connStrBuilder.ConnectionString);
connection.Open();
```

Gives me a System.ArgumentException: Invalid argument exception.
Examining the connection string the DB2ConnectionStringBuilder is creating shows the password is properly escaped:

> Database=databasename;User ID=username;Password="pass;word";Server=10.10.10.55:50000

Switching the password to "password" gets rid of that exception (of course I get username/password invalid).  Can this be a problem with the server?

Edit:  I am aware of this other post: [Escape ;(semicolon) in odbc connection string in app.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398212/escape-semicolon-in-odbc-connection-string-in-app-config-file)

I will add, I had tried to manually write the connection string using {} to escape instead of double quotes:

> server=10.10.10.55:50000;database=databasename;uid=username;pwd={pass;word};

but that gives me a slightly different exception "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index n" where 'n' is the index of the semicolon.  So it appears that DB2 doesn't recognize curly braces as valid escape characters.

Comment: What you need to do is *"escape"* the semi-colon character. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398212/escape-semicolon-in-odbc-connection-string-in-app-config-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escape ;(semicolon) in odbc connection string in app.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398212/escape-semicolon-in-odbc-connection-string-in-app-config-file)

Comment: I'm not sure.  I had seen that post before and tried to manually write the connection string using {} to escape instead of double quotes: `server=10.10.10.55:50000;database=databasename;uid=username;pwd={pass;word};` but that gives me a slightly different exception "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index n" where 'n' is the index of the semicolon.

Comment: Did you test your password with semi colon outside of c# to see if it actually works?

Comment: Yes, I used DBeaver and was able to connect fine.